# Color blocks on a slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I need to have color blocks on my slider like in the below image:

[Slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pmku8.png)

Please help me, I only found gradients everywhere.
I'm sorry, I don't know much about CSS

This is my current code:

```
<div style="width: 80%;height: 100px;background: #fff;display: flex;flex-flow: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;"><input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="6" style="
width: 90%;
margin-top: 35px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 12px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 20%, orange 40%, yellow 60%, lightgreen 80%, green 100%);
outline: none;
border-radius: 50px;
"></div>
```

Comment: working fine https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/k06xsn3z/4/

Comment: See the image with 'Slider' tag, I need color blocks not a gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two color stops that are the same, you can make a solid color instantly change to another solid color.

```html
<div style="width: 80%;height: 100px;background: #fff;display: flex;flex-flow: column;justify-content: center;align-items: center;"><input type="range" min="1" max="6" value="6" style="
width: 90%;
margin-top: 35px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
height: 12px;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 20%, orange 20%, orange 40%, yellow 40%, yellow 60%, lightgreen 60%, lightgreen 80%, green 80%, green 100%);
outline: none;
border-radius: 50px;
"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the colour blocks you're after:

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 20%, orange 20%, orange 40%, yellow 40%, yellow 60%, lightgreen 60%, lightgreen 80%, green 80%, green 100%);
```

Example [here](https://codepen.io/eddireeder/pen/pobzLZb)